# Redis cluster HA not working in kubernetes

Tags: redis, quarkus, bitnami, redis-cluster

I deployed `https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis-cluster`
with following command

`helm install redis-cluster bitnami/redis-cluster --create-namespace -n redis -f redis-values.yaml`

`redis-values.yaml`

```
cluster:
  init: true
  nodes: 6
  replicas: 1

podDisruptionBudget:
  minAvailable: 2

persistence:
  size: 1Gi

password: "redis@pass"

redis:
  configmap: |-
    maxmemory 600mb
    maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
    maxclients 40000
    cluster-require-full-coverage no
    cluster-allow-reads-when-down yes

sysctlImage:
  enabled: true
  mountHostSys: true
  command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - |-
      insta
      sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=10000
      echo never > /host-sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
#      echo never > /host-sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag


metrics:
  enabled: true
```

Now cluster working fine but issue only that if i will delete any pod then redis go down i start getting error for redis.

Here is my config for quarkus to connect:

```
quarkus.redis.hosts=redis://redis-cluster.redis.svc.local:6379
quarkus.redis.master-name=redis-cluster
quarkus.redis.password=redis@pass
quarkus.redis.client-type=cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't connect with service but use nodes change from

```
quarkus.redis.hosts=redis://redis-cluster:6379
```

To

```
quarkus.redis.hosts=redis://redis-cluster-0.redis-cluster-headless.redis.svc.cluster.local:6379,redis://redis-cluster-1.redis-cluster-headless.redis.svc.cluster.local:6379,redis://redis-cluster-2.redis-cluster-headless.redis.svc.cluster.local:6379,redis://redis-cluster-3.redis-cluster-headless.redis.svc.cluster.local:6379,redis://redis-cluster-4.redis-cluster-headless.redis.svc.cluster.local:6379,redis://redis-cluster-5.redis-cluster-headless.redis.svc.cluster.local:6379
```

Format for host is following:
`POD-NAME.HEADLESS-SVC-NAME.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local:PORT`

Comment: tried still same issue

Comment: Could you add some logs of the error, info about the k8s platform (GKE, AKS, minikube...) and version of k8s and chart? I've not been able to reproduce the error on minikube with the latest version of the chart